# binary search tree delete function deleting the same thing twice

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am trying to create a binary search tree that deletes the 2 leftmost nodes in a bst. For some reason, my code deletes the first value twice instead of moving onto the next.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct treeNode {
    char *word;                         // the string word that is stored
    int origin;                         // position of the word in the original text input’s line 1
    struct treeNode *left;              // pointer for the left children of the node
    struct treeNode *right;             // pointer for the right children of the node
    struct treeNode *parent;            // pointer for the parent of the node
};
typedef struct treeNode NODE;

NODE *
addNode(NODE * r, char *x)
{
    // r = root pointer of the tree
    // x = value to add into this tree
    // return the root of the updated tree
    NODE *p = malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    p->word = malloc(strlen(x) + 1);
    strcpy(p->word, x);                 // strcpy input: (destination, data to be copied)
    // printf("%s", x);
    p->parent = NULL;
    p->left = NULL;
    p->right = NULL;

// if tree is empty, tree consists of p only
    if (r == NULL)
        return p;

    if (strcmp(x, r->word) > 0) {

        r->right = addNode((r->right), x);
        return r;
    }
    else {
        // add new node the left subtree
        r->left = addNode((r->left), x);
        return r;
    }

    return r;

}

NODE *
getLeftMostNode(NODE * root)
{
    // return the pointer to the right most node
    if (root == NULL)
        return NULL;
    NODE *p = root;

    while (p->left != NULL)
        p = p->left;
    return p;
}

NODE *
addTree2Tree(NODE * X, NODE * Y)
{
    if (X == NULL)
        return Y;
    if (Y == NULL)
        return X;

    X = addNode(X, Y->word);
    X = addTree2Tree(X, Y->left);
    X = addTree2Tree(X, Y->right);
    return X;
}

NODE *
removeNode(NODE * r)
{
// remove any node that store value x from tree
// r: root pointer of this tree
// return root pointer of the updated tree after removal

    NODE *p = getLeftMostNode(r);

    NODE *C = p->parent;
    NODE *A = p->left;
    NODE *B = p->right;

    if (C == NULL) {
        // p is root of the tree
        free(p);
        return addTree2Tree(A, B);      // add tree A and tree B and return the new combination tree
    }
    if (A != NULL) {
        // make A a child of C assuming position of P
        if (p == C->left)
            C->left = A;
        else
            C->right = A;
        A->parent = C;
        free(p);
        return addTree2Tree(r, B);
    }
    if (B != NULL) {
        if (p == C->left)
            C->left = B;
        else
            C->right = B;
        B->parent = C;
        free(p);
        return r;
    }
    if (p == C->left)
        C->left = NULL;
    else
        C->right = NULL;
    free(p);                            // free allocation for p
    return r;

}

void
printArray(NODE * r)
{

// print all the values on the tree rooted at node "r" // print in alphabetical order

// if the tree is empty, return // print all the values on the tree rooted at node "r" // print in the in-order order: print left first, followed by root, followed by right values

    if (r == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    else {

        printArray(r->left);            // print all values in left subtree
        printf("%s ", r->word);
        printArray(r->right);           // print all values in right subtree

    }
}

int
main()
{
    // input must be implemented by linked list, not array
    NODE *root = NULL;
    int ch;
    char in[1000];                      // input array
    int len = 0;
    char del[100];                      // word to be deleted
    char word[1000];

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
        in[len++] = ch;
    in[len] = '\0';
    // printf("%s\n", in);

    int i = 0,
        j = 0;

    while (i <= len) {
        // space to store a word
        if ((in[i] == ' ') || (in[i] == '\0') || (in[i] == '\t')) {
            word[j] = '\0';             // end of word
            j = 0;
            root = addNode(root, word);
            // printf("%s\n", word);
        }
        else
            word[j++] = in[I];
        i++;

    }
    int k = 0;

    removeNode(root);
    removeNode(root);

    printArray(root);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

this is the error that I got

Comment: Why does addNode allocate multiple nodes recursively then leak them?

Comment: Without even looking at `removeNode`, we can tell that `removeNode(root);` is obviously wrong. What if there's only one node left in the tree? `root` would need to be modified.

Comment: Tip: `p->word = malloc(strlen(x) + 1); strcpy(p->word, x);` can be simplified to `p->word = strdup(x);`

Answer (score 2):

The function `removeNode` is looking for `parent`, but `parent` is never assigned in `addNode`. You want to assign `r->right->parent = r;` and `r->left->parent = r;`.

BST doesn't keep duplicate keys. If `strcmp(x, r->word) == 0`, then don't add a new node.

`addNode` should also be corrected so that if `r` is `NULL`, the function returns the new node immediately.

```
NODE* addNode(NODE* r, char* x)
{
    if(!x) 
        return NULL;

    if (!r)
    {
        NODE* p = malloc(sizeof(NODE)); if (!p) return NULL;
        p->word = strdup(x);
        p->parent = NULL;
        p->left = NULL;
        p->right = NULL;
        return p;
    }

    if (strcmp(x, r->word) > 0) 
    {
        r->right = addNode((r->right), x);
        r->right->parent = r;
        return r;
    }
    else if (strcmp(x, r->word) < 0)
    {
        r->left = addNode((r->left), x);
        r->left->parent = r;
        return r;
    }

    return r;
}
```

Modify the insert functions such that `root` is assigned only once:

```
while (i <= len) 
{
    if ((in[i] == ' ') || (in[i] == '\0') || (in[i] == '\t')) 
    {
        word[j] = '\0';             
        j = 0;
        if(!root)
            root = addNode(root, word);
        else
            addNode(root, word);
    }
    else
        word[j++] = in[i];
    i++;
}
```

Double check the pointers to make sure `NULL` pointers are avoided. For example:

```
NODE* removeNode(NODE* r)
{
    if(!r)
        return NULL;
    NODE* p = getLeftMostNode(r);
    if(!p)
        return NULL;
    ...
}
```

I have not checked the rest of the code but the example will work with these changes made.